# Misleading warning from BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

Accidentally, I discovered a misleading warning. By mistake, I left the citation argument empty, compiled and run BibTeX. BibTeX warned that 'RealCitation' was not found in the database. After I remove the \cite{}, it compiles fine. I guess this issue would be better fixed (or maybe message changed)

```
\cite{RealCitation}
\cite{}
```

Comment: If I load `natbib`, I get `Warning--I didn't find a database entry for ""` and `\cite{}` does nothing; without `natbib`, I get no warning, but `\cite{}` prints just the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a test file such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{RealCitation}
\cite{}
\cite{zz}
\end{document}
```

Then you see the generated `aux` file is

```
\relax 
\citation{RealCitation}
\citation{zz}
```

and LaTeX has silently ignored the `\cite{}` so BiBTeX has no information that it was ever there, and it can not affect the bibtex output. If it is affecting the generated warnings there is additional code that you have not shown.